# How to convert all non numeric cells in data frame to NA

Tags: r, missing-data

I am trying to convert all cells with non-numeric values to missing data (NA). I tried something similar along the lines of converting specific values to missing data, like:

```
recode_missing <- function (g, misval)
{
  a <- g == misval
  temp = g
  temp [a] <- NA
  return (temp)
}
```

That works great: an elegant R solution.

I tried to decode like `a <- g == is.numeric ()` (syntactically wrong), `a <- is.numeric (g): (Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'), or even`a [,] <- is.numeric (g[,]` (same). I an aware of the solution of removing columns

```
remove_nn <- function (data)
{
  # removes all non-numeric columns
  numeric_columns <- sapply (data, is.numeric)
  return (data [, numeric_columns])
} ### remove_nn ###
```

But that removes the columns and converts the data frame to some matrix.

Could someone please advise on how to convert single non-numeric cells to NA while leaving the data structure intact?

**Edit**

As the comments point out correctly there is no such thing as an individual string value in an ocean of numeric values. Just vectors which are numeric or something else. What I now wanted to know what caused the non-numeric error in `medians <- apply (data, 2, median)`. I have many vectors and inspection by eye proved useless. I issued `num <- sapply (data, is.numeric)` and next `data [,!num]`. That gave me the columns that were non-numeric. In one case that was caused by *one* cell value containing a superfluous ". The file is preprocessed by a spreadsheet and if just one cell is non-numeric, the complete vector is seen as non-numeric.

Comment: A value in a column cannot be numeric independently. Either the column is numeric or it isn't. Can you provide an example?

Comment: did you try something like `lapply(data, function(i) as.numeric(as.character(i)))`?

Comment: I suspect you would want something like `mydf[] <- lapply(mydf, as.numeric)` -- which @Sotos just beat me to ;-)

Comment: Arnold -- I think you need to clarify this question....

Comment: Please, explain (or provide reproducible sample data) what your understanding is of _single non-numeric cells_ and what your _data structure_ is. R is working on vectors (well, mainly) which are all of the same type. I'm guessing wildly that you might be talking about a character vector which may contain character strings which could be converted to numeric.

Comment: Everyone +1 for pointing at my stupidity. It is a beginners mistake which I (un)fortunately am ;-) I have added an Edit to my question to explain what I have done. This was all inspired by your comments. Thanks very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your edit, you have vectors which should be numeric, but due to some erroneous data introduced during the reading-in process, the data have been converted to another format (likely `character` or `factor`).

Here is an example of that case. `mydf1 <- mydf2 <- mydf3 <-
 data.frame(...)` just creates three `data.frame`s with the same data.

```
# I'm going to show three approaches
mydf1 <- mydf2 <- mydf3 <- data.frame(
  A = c(1, 2, "x", 4),
  B = c("y", 3, 4, "-")
)

str(mydf1)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ A: Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","4","x": 1 2 4 3
#  $ B: Factor w/ 4 levels "-","3","4","y": 4 2 3 1
```

One way to do this is to just let R coerce any values that cannot be converted to numeric to `NA`:

```
## You WILL get warnings
mydf1[] <- lapply(mydf1, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
# Warning messages:
# 1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
# 2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion

str(mydf1)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ A: num  1 2 NA 4
#  $ B: num  NA 3 4 NA
```

Another option is to use `makemeNA` from [my SOfun package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun):

```
library(SOfun)
makemeNA(mydf2, "[^0-9]", FALSE)
#    A  B
# 1  1 NA
# 2  2  3
# 3 NA  4
# 4  4 NA

str(.Last.value)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ A: int  1 2 NA 4
#  $ B: int  NA 3 4 NA
```

This function is a bit different in that it uses `type.convert` to do the conversion, and can handle more specific rules for conversion to `NA` (just like you can use a vector for `na.strings` when reading data into R).

---

About your error, I believe you would have tried `as.numeric` on your `data.frame` to get the error you had shown.

Example:

```
# Your error...
as.numeric(mydf3)
# Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

You won't get that error on a `matrix` though (but you'll still get the warning)....

```
# You'll get a warning
as.numeric(as.matrix(mydf3))
# [1]  1  2 NA  4 NA  3  4 NA
# Warning message:
# NAs introduced by coercion
```

Why don't we need to explicitly use `as.character`? `as.matrix` does that for you:

```
str(as.matrix(mydf3))
#  chr [1:4, 1:2] "1" "2" "x" "4" "y" "3" "4" "-"
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   ..$ : NULL
#   ..$ : chr [1:2] "A" "B"
```

How can you use that information?

```
mydf3[] <- as.numeric(as.matrix(mydf3))
# Warning message:
# NAs introduced by coercion 

str(mydf3)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ A: num  1 2 NA 4
#  $ B: num  NA 3 4 NA
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the background of my question. I did get the coercion errors at some point and now know what they mean. Missing data are a pain in the ass and it has taken me at least a day to get some basic understanding. Any additional explanation -like this answer- helps.

Comment: @Arnold, OK. I've added some more information that is hopefully helpful.

Comment: @ A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1, that's extremely generous of you! I already applied some of your suggestions and they really help. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Simple is best. Choose columns - I chose columns 4 through to 31.

```
df[,4:31] <- as.numeric(as.factor(as.character(df[,4:31])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tidyverse solution.

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = c(1, 2, "x", 4),
  B = c("y", 3, 4, "-"),
  C = 4:7
)
```

Using `mutate` and `across` from dplyr we can say "Make any non-numeric column numeric". This will *implicitly* convert any values which aren't numbers into `NA`, and it will give you a warning.

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(across(!where(is.numeric), as.numeric))
```

To do it explicitly we could do something with regular expressions.

This says, that for any non-numeric column, if a value has any character in it which **isn't** 0-9, then make it `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# This would leave the columns as character vectors.
df |>
  mutate(across(
    !where(is.numeric),
    ~ if_else(str_detect(.x, "[^0-9]"), NA, .x)
  ))

# To make them numeric vectors (as in the other examples):
df |>
  mutate(across(
    !where(is.numeric),
    ~ if_else(str_detect(.x, "[^0-9]"), NA, .x) |>
      as.numeric()
  ))
```

Note that these solutions are slightly stricter than the other answers given, using `!where(is.numeric)` we only operate on the non-numeric columns, it won't make any difference to the output but will be faster if you have many columns.

For completeness here is the tidyverse copy of

```r
lapply(mydf1, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ as.numeric(as.character(.x))))
```